# Use crontab in Ubuntu with LAMPP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, lampp

I googled for quite some time already, but I still can't find how to setup crontab with lampp.

I need to run a PHP script for every 15 minutes.

So, in bash:

```
$ sudo -i
# crontab -e
```

I get a nano editor... what should I type inside?

I tried `* * * * */opt/lampp/path/to/script` but it's not working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I would suggest to make a bash script and run that in the crontab instead. I always had problems with setting a command in crontab. You have to take into account that crontab works in a different enviroment.

Comment: I think that as long as you have `#!/usr/bin/php` on the first line, make the file executable, and add whatever PHP-specific stuff is needed in the body of the script (`<?php` ... `?>`), it should be ok.

Comment: @Pithikos Thanks for your reply , can I get some examples or steps on how to make a bash script ? I totally new in cron and I don't know much about it...

Comment: @Irene Ling you just put '#! /bin/bash' as first line in a file and then add the commands you want to run. Commands are any commands you would normally put in a terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crontab script is

```
* * * * */opt/lampp/path/to/script
```

Maybe the reason is you don't have a space between the last '*' and the first '/'...

Try this:

```
* * * * * /opt/lampp/path/to/script
```

Comment: That runs every minute, not every 15 minutes. Replace the first * with e.g. */15

Comment: @Iya Thank you so much for your reply Iya.
Let's say my path is /opt/lampp/htdocs/testing.php , so I put 
* * * * * /opt/lampp/htdocs/testing.php , but it's still not working.

Comment: @Iya or is there anything I should add in my testing.php? actually I don't know what is my php path .

Comment: @Irene Ling Of course it doesn't work, because your testing.php is not an executable. You have to use `php /opt/.../testing.php` to execute the script.

Comment: @Iya Thank you Iya , I understand now and finally it works. Really thanks for your help.

Comment: @tripleee Thankyou tripleee , I will replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use `php path/to/script` to run the PHP script: Ubuntu may not know how to run the script directly. You do have to have php-cli installed for that to work, too.